# How to get currently selected product id of configurable product on view page?

Tags: product, configurable-product, product-attribute, price, magento2.3

I need to **change name, price, SKU and more when options are clicked.**
So I need the **product ID** of the selected option in the product view page.
I have a **Custom phtml** file to write my own alteration in the product view page.
 How to get **productId** in this file on clicking the options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the associated Simple Product ID and Quantity using below code.

Add the below code Javascript and PHP at the beginning of this file

> app/design/frontend/Theme_Namespace/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/ templates/product/view/Your_phtmlfile

```
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery','underscore'], function(jQuery,_){
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery( ".product-options-wrapper div" ).click(function() {
        selpro();
    });
});
function selpro () {
    var selected_options = {};
    jQuery('div.swatch-attribute').each(function(k,v){
        var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('attribute-id');
        var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('option-selected');
        //console.log(attribute_id, option_selected);
        if(!attribute_id || !option_selected){ return;}
        selected_options[attribute_id] = option_selected;
    });

    var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;
    var found_ids = [];
    //console.log(product_id_index);
    jQuery.each(product_id_index, function(product_id,attributes){
        //console.log(product_id);
        var productIsSelected = function(attributes, selected_options){
            return _.isEqual(attributes, selected_options);
        }
        if(productIsSelected(attributes, selected_options)){
            found_ids.push(product_id);
        } 
    });
    
    //console.log(found_ids);

    if (found_ids.length) {
        var selected_product_id = found_ids[0];
        jQuery('.myli').css('display','none');
        jQuery('#div'+selected_product_id).toggle();
    }
}
});
</script>
```

For Magento 2.4.0 version, change the below code from

```
var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('attribute-id');
var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('option-selected');
```

to

```
var attribute_id = jQuery(v).attr('data-attribute-id');
var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('data-option-selected');
```

And PHP code.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);
?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) { ?>
                <li class="myli" id="div<?php echo $child->getId()?>" style="display:none;list-style:none">
                    <?php 
                    $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($child->getId());
                    echo "We have ".round($productStockObj->getData('qty'))." items in stock!";
                    ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul> 
<?php 
    } else {
        $productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product->getId());
        echo "We have ".round($productStockObj->getData('qty'))." items in stock!";
    }
?>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day

Comment: You are welcome. happy to help :)

Comment: How to get product id in custom module

Comment: In which file you want product id?

Comment: it is not working on my side. It is giving error on here:     var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;

It says that it is undefined. Any help? I'm using magento 2.3.3

Comment: @GerardoSiano You may be getting this error because of '[data-role=swatch-options]' you have to debug from your end to find `product_id_index` 
To find id enable debugger and search for `swatch-opt-` you will see `product_id_index`

Comment: If I inspect the element, I find swatch-options, but I don't find mageSwatchRenderer.

Comment: @ChiragPatel any suggestion? Still didn't find a solution :/

Comment: I will update you if I found something.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Is this script correct? this is not working at my end

Comment: It is working for me. might be you may do something wrong.

Comment: @ChiragPatel it's not working for Magento 2.4.0 version but below this version it's fine. can you please update

Comment: i have not checked yet in magento 2.4.0. letter i will check

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

The above code works only if the swatches enabled. Please use the following code which will get all dropdown attributes values on the dropdown change event and please the values to the custom module using the ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','underscore'], function(jQuery,_){
    var confProductId = jQuery('.price-box').attr('data-product-id');
    jQuery(".product-options-wrapper select[id^='attribute']").on('change', function() {
        var data = [];
        var $el=jQuery(".product-options-wrapper select[id^='attribute']");
        $el.each(function(){
            data.push({selectedValue:jQuery(this).val(),selectedAttributeId:jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('attribute', '')});
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>/getweekprice/index/index",
            type: "POST",
            data: { confProductId:confProductId,params: data },
            showLoader: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                jQuery('#product-detail-week-prices').html(response).append("<span class='day-text week-text'>per week (ex.VAT)</span>");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Custom module controller code.

```
    <?php 

namespace Confproducts\Weekpricesimpleprod\Controller\Index; 

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $jsonHelper;
    protected $productObj;
    protected $configurableProTypeModel;
    protected $logger;
    protected $currency;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableProTypeModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $currency,
        \Confproducts\Weekpricesimpleprod\Logger\Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->configurableProTypeModel = $configurableProTypeModel;
        $this->productObj = $productRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->currency = $currency;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $attributesInfo = array();
            $getAjaxPostValues = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $product = $this->productObj->getById( $getAjaxPostValues['confProductId'] );

            foreach( $getAjaxPostValues['params'] as $attributeData ) {

                if( empty( $attributeData['selectedValue'] ) )
                {
                    return $this->jsonResponse( $this->currency->currency(0.00,true, false ) );
                }
                 $attributesInfo[$attributeData['selectedAttributeId']] =  $attributeData['selectedValue'];
            }

            $associateProduct = $this->configurableProTypeModel->getProductByAttributes($attributesInfo, $product);
            $getWeekPrice = $associateProduct->getData('week_price');
            $weekPrice =  round( $getWeekPrice,2 );
            $formattedWeekPrice = $this->currency->currency( $weekPrice,true,false);
           // $this->logger->log(100,print_r($getAjaxPostValues,true));
            return $this->jsonResponse( $formattedWeekPrice );
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return $this->jsonResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create json response
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function jsonResponse($response = '')
    {
        return $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($response)
        );
    }}
```